# Repetitive PyQT references

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I have a PyQT UI designed in QT Designer, with 40 figures (on different tabs), and a bunch of repetitive references to elements in the UI. For example, the following unique text fields, which are used to set the title of each figure.

```
    # Tab 1
    self.tab1_tl1.canvas.axes.set_title(self.tab1_tl1_title.text())
    self.tab1_tl2.canvas.axes.set_title(self.tab1_tl2_title.text())
    self.tab1_tl3.canvas.axes.set_title(self.tab1_tl3_title.text())
    self.tab1_tl4.canvas.axes.set_title(self.tab1_tl4_title.text())
    self.tab1_tl1.canvas.axes.set_ylabel(self.tab1_tl1_ylabel.text())
    self.tab1_tl2.canvas.axes.set_ylabel(self.tab1_tl2_ylabel.text())
    self.tab1_tl3.canvas.axes.set_ylabel(self.tab1_tl3_ylabel.text())
    self.tab1_tl4.canvas.axes.set_ylabel(self.tab1_tl4_ylabel.text())
    # Tab 2
    self.tab2_tl1.canvas.axes.set_title(self.tab2_tl1_title.text())
    self.tab2_tl2.canvas.axes.set_title(self.tab2_tl2_title.text())
    self.tab2_tl3.canvas.axes.set_title(self.tab2_tl3_title.text())
    self.tab2_tl4.canvas.axes.set_title(self.tab2_tl4_title.text())
    self.tab2_tl1.canvas.axes.set_ylabel(self.tab2_tl1_ylabel.text())
    self.tab2_tl2.canvas.axes.set_ylabel(self.tab2_tl2_ylabel.text())
    self.tab2_tl3.canvas.axes.set_ylabel(self.tab2_tl3_ylabel.text())
    self.tab2_tl4.canvas.axes.set_ylabel(self.tab2_tl4_ylabel.text())
```

As you can imagine, the code gets very wordy. Is there a more efficient way to loop through all these references and fields?

Comment: You could use `getattr` and `setattr` e.g. or store your elements in a `list` or the like. But a good solution also depends a lot on the context and your personal preferences.

Comment: You should decompose more. Single ui-file with several tabs and figures doesn't seem to be a good design solution. It should be separate widgets, as small as possible.

Comment: Are the `tab1_tl1` objects promoted widgets from Qt Designer? If so, you could use [QObject.findChildren](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren-2) with a regexp to extract all of them into a list based on their `objectName`. Then you could iterate over that and use the `objectName` to get the other widgets, like so: `title = getattr(self, f'{widget.objectName()}_title').text()`. Potentially, that could reduce the whole thing to 3-4 lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments, you could use `getattr`, but without further context, this is the best I can suggest:

```py
for i in range(1, 41):
    for j in range(1, 5):
        ax = getattr(self, f'tab{i}_tl{j}').canvas.axes
        title = getattr(self, f'tab{i}_tl{j}_title').text()
        ylabel = getattr(self, f'tab{i}_tl{j}_ylabel').text()
        ax.set_title(title)
        ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)
```

Comment: Thanks mapf, this worked perfectly! I applied it to other areas of my code, and reduced the program from about 2300 lines to 1400 lines.

Comment: Now down to 730 lines. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should put the corresponding tl, title and ylabel in a dictionary and arange them in a nested list instead of putting names as `tab1_tl1`

Create them like this:

```
tabs = [] 
for i in range(tabCount):
    tab = []
    tabs.append(tab)

    for j in range(tlCount):
        tab.append(dict(
          obj = create_tl(i,j)),
          title = create_title(i,j),
          ylabel = create_ylabel(i,j)  )
```

Now `tabs[i][j]` correspond to `tabi_tlj` and it is a dict containing the acutal tl object, the title and the ylabel.
So you can update the properties like this:

```
for tab in tabs:        
    for tl in tab:
        tl['obj'].canvas.axes.set_title(tl['title'])
        tl['obj'].canvas.axes.set_ylabel(tl['ylabel'])
```

In general create numbered variables is not good. Lists are there for that. Also always gather related repeated objects in dicts or objects.

Comment: This approach won't really work in this case, because the attributes are all auto-generated from a ui file created by Qt Designer.